# How do I avoid returning None type when an empty list is passed as an argument?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

```
def first_even(items):
    """ (list of int) -> int

    Return the first even number from items. Return -1 if items contains no even numbers.

    >>> first_even([5, 8, 3, 2])
    8
    >>> first_even([7, 1])
    -1
    """
    counter = 0
    for item in items:
        counter = counter + 1
        if item % 2 == 0:
            return item
        elif counter == len(items):
            return -1
```

Details Details Details Details Details

Comment: "Details Details Details Details Details"? Are you expecting an answer with "Code Code Answer Explanation Code"?

Answer (score 1):

You can also return `-1` in that case:

```
counter = 0
for item in items:
    counter = counter + 1
    if item % 2 == 0:
        return item
    elif counter == len(items):
        return -1
return -1
```

When `items` is empty the for loop simply won't return and it'll go directly to the last line which is `return -1`.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you so much ! Is this because an empty list doesn't agree with any of the if statements ?

Comment: No, when `items` is empty the line `for item in items:` has nothing to do. So the whole for loop is skipped and it'll run the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different approach: raise an exception when no even integer is found. Here's an implementation:

```
def first_even(items):
    """Returns the first even integer in an iterable producing ints.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the iterable contains no even integers, or is in fact
        empty.
    """
    for item in items:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            return item
    else:
        raise ValueError('The list contains no even items.')
```

Why raise an exception? If you use a return value of `-1` to signal an error, then using your function becomes tricky in some cases. For example, suppose I want to check if the first even integer in a list is negative:

```
if first_even([3, -4, 5, 8]) < 0:
    print('The first even integer is negative!')
```

This will work for *that* input, but what about:

```
if first_even([1, 3, 5]) < 0:
    print('The first even integer is negative!')
```

This will print the message anyways!

Comment: Yes, I would usually put a print message in cases of errors but, for the purpose of an assignment I am doing it needs to return -1 haha. Thank you though ! I appreciate the time you took to suggest this.